# How did Bane get out of the pit/prison in The Dark Knight Rises?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-dark-knight-rises

In [The Dark Knight Rises](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1345836), till the end of the movie the audience would be think like, the kid get out from the pit was **Bane**. But, in the climatic scene the movie revealed that the kid wasn't Bane, it was Talia.

Furthermore, when Bruce was in the pit, his inmates used to say there was only one person escaped/get out from the pit and that was a small kid. According to the movie it was Talia. Then, ***how's it possible for Bane to get out from the pit?***

Answer (score 21, accepted):

After Talia escapes, she informs Ra's Al Ghul of Bane; so he comes to the prison & rescues Bane (this scene is shown for a short time ~5 seconds), and later trains him.

Comment: Yep - we get that lovely abseiling scene that reminded me of an old James Bond film, much like the last 45 mins.

Comment: Thanks @karthik. Again i watched the  (~5 seconds) scene very closely, and you're right :)

Answer (score 5):

Essentially what happened was, Talia's mother was imprisoned (because of Ra's Al Ghul if I remember correctly) and gave birth to Talia.  At one point something happens and they start beating on Talia's mother.  To protect her Bane put Talia up on the wall so that Talia could escape while he fought them off.

Talia finds her father and brings him back to the pit, where they discover a broken (but kinda repaired) Bane.  The League of Shadows takes over the prison, and Bane somewhat becomes Talia's body guard/confidant.

Answer (score 4):

Talia explains to Bruce how she was the one who escaped the pit and went to find her father once she escaped. Ra's Al Ghul and the League of Shadows came back to

> "exact terrible vengeance"

So it was Ra's and the League of Shadows that helped Bane escape from the pit so he didn't make the jump and escape like Talia and Bruce did.